# Is there a way to restore recently-deleted user using Java from Azure AD?

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory

Title I guess is self explanatory.

I haven't tried anything yet as I haven't seen a sample approach from Microsoft.

The end result should be that when I go to Azure portal and go to Active directory, the user deleted will be back in the Active Users list (Removed from "Deleted Users").

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Microsoft Graph SDK for Java](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java) to do this.

```
graphClient.directory().deletedItems("{deletedItemId}").restore();
```

Or you can call [graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-restore?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript) directly.

```
POST /directory/deletedItems/{id}/restore
```

Comment: Thanks Caiji, I will try your suggestions first :-)

Comment: Sorry no updates yet :-( as I was stumped with other priorities. This I can say though: graph api using POST by MS, is not working for me. I got a 411 error which means wrong content-length in the header. I tried adding that value with a "Content-length" = "0". But still not able to. I tried looking for a solution but did not get any yet. So I will try again very soon. But for this purpose. I think your answer is what I need. thanks @caiyu-ju